# Failed to resolve: com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2

Tags: android

[image: 1]

I have added this dependency but still gradle is not able to sync and gives Failed to resolve: com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2

I dont know where i went wrong

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: no this question is not related to firebase .. i just wrote with what i'm working with

Answer (score 0):

In your app level Gradle you might be using mavenCentral().
You need to add jcenter() as well in that.
For older plugins you need jcenter.
See this code of the library to make the required changes
https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton/blob/master/build.gradle